# Apache load balancer unable to distinguish between different subdomains

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I am trying to configure an Apache load balancer to route requests to a number of backend servers but for some reason it seems that the main domain's content is always being loaded, regardless of the subdomain that is specified. For example, loading the site games.example.com should be loading the /var/www/example_games content on the backend server but instead it loads the content at /var/www/example (ie. the main domain). I have tested by exposing the backend server and the apache configuration works fine on the backend itself to load each subdomain correctly but it seems to be a problem with this load balancer configuration where the information about the subdomain is 'lost' resulting in the main domain's (example.com) content to load despite specifying games.example.com. Here is the load balancer config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # SSL certificate configurations
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
        BalancerMember http://172.16.111.10 loadfactor=1
    #    BalancerMember http://172.16.111.11 loadfactor=10
    #    BalancerMember http://172.16.111.12 loadfactor=10
    #    BalancerMember http://172.16.111.13 loadfactor=10
        # Add more BalancerMembers if you have additional backend servers
        # BalancerMember http://backend-server3-ip:backend-server3-port route=server3
        # ...
        ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
        #ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
        #ProxySet nofailover=On
    </Proxy>    
    
    
    
    #Main domain
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
        ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/


        <Location "/balancer-manager">
            SetHandler balancer-manager
            Require host localhost
        </Location>

        <Location "/server-status">
            SetHandler server-status
            Require host localhost
        </Location>
    </VirtualHost>



    #GAMES DOMAIN
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName games.example.com
        Options -Indexes
        RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
        ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/


        <Location "/balancer-manager">
            SetHandler balancer-manager
            Require host localhost
        </Location>

        <Location "/server-status">
            SetHandler server-status
            Require host localhost
        </Location>
    </VirtualHost>



    #CDN DOMAIN
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName cdn.example.com
        Options -Indexes

        RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
        ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
        ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/


        <Location "/balancer-manager">
            SetHandler balancer-manager
            Require host localhost
        </Location>

        <Location "/server-status">
            SetHandler server-status
            Require host localhost
        </Location>
    </VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, the `ProxyPreserveHost On` directive was required for each block to be able to forward the request header to the backend server. Hope it helps anyone else with a similar problem.